# Making a tree where some nodes contain node objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I want to create a tree using tikz. However, I have a few constraints. Most of the nodes at all the levels are standard usual nodes. However, I want to have the following at some level (say level 3) in this tree:

1. All nodes at this level should be drawn bigger (perhaps elliptical).
2. Moreover, I also want each of these big nodes to contain some dots. In the picture below, I mark these dots in purple. There is a "home" node for these purple dots where most of them live. And a few of these purple dots appear in other nodes at this level.[image]

I can add the tikz code I obtained from online sources to create trees, but it is pretty bare-bones. Please let me know if that would be helpful in getting help with this question.

**EDIT** (Added Later)

Here are some variations that I tried so far on overleaf. Mostly, it revolves around attempts to define some new node objects. But then the picture I end up with is not particularly nice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}

\tikzset{
    standard/.style = {circle, white, draw=black, inner sep = 1.5},
    containerNode/.style={circle, draw=black, minimum size=1cm, node contents=\draw \Huge $\dots$ $\dots$ $\dots$},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
    \scalebox{.6}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1,level distance = 2cm}]
            \node [standard] (z){}
            child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]
                    child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]}
                    child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]}
                }
                child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                    child {node [containerNode] (a) {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                        child {node [standard] (x) {}edge from parent[draw=black, very thin]}
                        child {node [standard] (y) {}edge from parent[draw=black, very thin]}
                    }
                    child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]}
                }
            }
            child { node [standard] {} edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                    child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]
                    }
                    child {node [standard] (b) {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]}
                }
                child {node [standard] {}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]
                    child {node [standard] (c){}edge from parent [draw=black, very thin]}
                    child {node [standard] {} edge from parent [draw=black,very thin]}
                }
            };

        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    
 \end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

The image generated on overleaf is shown below.

[image]

*Apologies* for the huge delay in adding the edits.

Comment: reminds me of aliens

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: We all are very impatient to read your edit ;)

Comment: Sorry about the delay in adding the pictures. SebGlav guess I owe you a beer :-)